# On disabling UIButton, it hides

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have added a custom UIButton. I am trying to disable the button,but the button hides. Please help

Comment: Could you post some code so we can have more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
myButton.enabled = NO;
myButton.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks, i have disable the button using the syntax above..but the button vanishes from the view :(